# Converting six-bit binary number to it's corresponding two digit BCD number?

Tags: digital, rom, bcd, digital-design

Here is the question that I tried so hard but I couldn't solve it.
 
I captured the question as it was from the question-paper, I couldn't solve it in the exam, and non of student's could.
You probably ask, why don't you ask your lecturer ( it's fair question because you are not here to solve the exam-question or a homework), we did but she didn't solve it she just told us the BCD is like this :

```
10^0   10^1   10^2 ....
```

[image]

Any Help appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like what she wants is for you to specify the binary [BCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) output for these inputs. So, for example, 53 would output as 101 0011 (starting from D6). (101 = 5, 0011 = 3)

Answer (score 1):

7.17,The 32 * 6 ROM, together with the 20 line, as shown in Fig. P7.17, converts a six‐bit binary
number to its corresponding two‐digit BCD number. For example, binary 100001 converts
to BCD 011 0011 (decimal 33). Specify the truth table for the ROM.[see the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1nNX.jpg)